# Issue Packaging Salesforce Wave Analytics

Tags: json, einstein-analytics, analytics

I created a Salesforce Wave Analytics package, which I'm hoping to be able to install in other orgs so that the other orgs have the Wave dashboards I've built out. The issue I'm running into is that the package copies the dashboard JSON file which contains a reference to the dataset ID.

```
{"id": "0aa1A000000Aa1ABAS",
"label": "Data",
"name": "Data",
"namespace": "Salesforce",
"url": "/services/data/v41.0/wave/datasets/0aa1A000000Aa1ABAS"}
```

Is there any way to make this a variable that will load the data in the org that the package is being installed into?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one package include Dataset, Dashboard. Dataflow(If any), Recipe(If any).
2. Migrate it into target org.
   NOTE: After Migrating the package you will not be able to see Dataset in that org.
3. Run the Dataflow/ Recipe. (If there is any dataflow or recipe).
4. Upload csv File. File name has to be same as dataset name. (If there is not dataflow or Recipe then follow this process).
5. Once dataset will be available then you can open dashboard.

Kind Regards,

Shaleen Basak